# Let $x\in\Bbb R$, $a=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}$, and $b=\inf\{-s\mid s\in\Bbb Q,s<x\}$. Prove that $a+b=\inf\{r-s \mid r,s\in\Bbb Q,s<x<r\}$

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

> Let $x,y\in\Bbb R$. We define  addition operation $(+)$ by $$x+ y:=\inf\{r+ s\mid r,s\in\Bbb Q \text{ and } x<r  \text{ and } y<s\}$$
>
> **Theorem:** Let $x\in\Bbb R$, $a=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}$, and $b=\inf\{-s\mid s\in\Bbb Q,s<x\}$. Prove that $$a+b=\inf\{r-s \mid r,s\in\Bbb Q,s<x<r\}$$

This is a theorem that the authors of my textbook **Introduction to Set Theory** by Hrbacek and Jech leave as an exercise. The theorem is from Chapter 10. Sets of Real Numbers. Could you please verify my attempt? Thank you for your help!

---

**My attempt:**

It is clear that $a=x$ from $a=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}$.

By definition, $a+b=\inf\{r+p\mid r,p\in\Bbb Q,a<r,b<p\}=\inf\{r+p\mid r,p\in\Bbb Q,x<r,b<p\}$.

Substituting $-p$ for $p$, we get $a+b=\inf\{r-p\mid r,-p\in\Bbb Q,x<r,b<-p\}=$ $\inf\{r-p\mid r,p\in\Bbb Q,x<r,b<-p\}$.

We have $p\in\Bbb Q$ and $b<-p \iff p\in\Bbb Q$ and $-p>-s$ for some $s\in\Bbb Q$ such that $s<x$ $\iff p\in\Bbb Q$ and $p<s$ for some $s\in\Bbb Q$ such that $s<x$ $\iff p=s$ for some $s\in\Bbb Q$ such that $s<x$.

It follows that $a+b=\inf\{r-p\mid r,p\in\Bbb Q,x<r,b<-p\}=$ $\inf\{r-s\mid r,s\in\Bbb Q,x<r,s<x\}=\inf\{r-s\mid r,s\in\Bbb Q,s<x<r\}.$

Comment: Hi @KaviRamaMurthy, I could not see the mentioned typos. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Which book are you referring to? Please [edit] the question to include the details.

Comment: Thank you @Shaun! I have edited to include the name of textbook.

Comment: This exercise is about [construction of the real number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers). When you say *It is clear that $a=x$ from $a=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}$*, do you mean it is clear from your knowledge of the reals (which won’t be fine!) or clear from theorems proved previously in the exercise (which would be OK). I doubt that you’re in the later case as you won’t have proved existence and unicity of infimum before defining addition. Which is the exercise about. **For this exercise, forget all what you know about the real numbers!**

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, I conclude $a=\inf \{r \mid r\in\Bbb Q,x<r\}$ from the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ (I learned this property when studying Dedekind Cuts). Through the proof, I only use the properties of addition and multiplication defined on $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung OK, understand! And what you did seems fine.

Comment: Hi @mathcounterexamples.net, Thank you for your comment! Anyway, it is beneficial ^^